# SQL Server throwing divide by zero in a union query but individual queries working fine

Tags: sql-server, union, divide-by-zero

I have a complex query. Simplified, it looks like

```
select x,y... from table1 
UNION 
select x,y... from table2 
UNION 
select x,y... from table3 
UNION 
select x,y... from table4
UNION 
select x,y... from table5 
UNION 
select x,y... from table6
```

All these queries work fine when I run them individually. They even work fine when I use first 3 and last 3 queries in separate unions but it starts throwing divided by zero error when I run all of them together. Is there any workaround for this. It is just a temporary query for my research and analysis. So even an inefficient solution will work for now

Comment: I think we need to see the full queries, can you include at least say two of them?  My guess is that you're dividing by zero somewhere as a result of the `UNION`.

Comment: Examine the execution plans. What is likely happening is that, when composed into the full union, some `SELECT` clause calculations are being pushed deeper (earlier) into the plan and are being evaluated in rows that the `WHERE` clauses should eliminate. *logically* there should be no error, but SQL Server sometimes charmingly violates the logical processing order and gives you an error instead.

Comment: Temporary solution can be to use a temp table, just insert data from each query to your temp table, then query from temp table for final result

Comment: Yes Damien, I was thinking along similar lines, It must be some quirk of SQL Server. Thank You Kim, I will do what you suggested.

Comment: Are you worried about having duplicate rows as a result of the multiple queries?  If not, try using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @iamdave, UNION ALL is also having the same issue. I have just worked around the problem by individually inserting results of all queries into a temp table and then removing dups. Good, it is only for analysis and not some prod process.